# C# Browser control with advanced(not) functions

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, awesomium, geckofx, cefsharp

I am looking for a web browser component for C# WinForms with following functionality:

- Multi-session support (separate handling of cookies and other content per browser instance; ability to use/connect to separate proxy server per instance)
- Interfacing with DOM (reading/editing DOM elements directly **without Javascript**)
- Prefferably support of multithreading.

So far I have tested these wrappers:

**[Awesomium.NET](http://www.awesomium.com/)** - Supports Multiple sessions, is multithreaded but does **not provide means to directly interface with DOM. (without JS)**

**[CEFSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)** - Same as above.

**[GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/)** - No multiple session support (per application), **has capability to interact with DOM. (without JS)**

Is there a browser control that supports all of these features?

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/825526/Csharp-WebBrowser-vs-Gecko-vs-Awesomium-vs-OpenWeb) article supports my experience so far with these three controls.

Comment: Awesomium.NET project is dead

Comment: Those who voted 'Close', dare I ask, why?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I believe I have stated the problem. Posting any code is meaningless due to essence of the question itself.

Comment: I just quoted the close reason text. I would recommend to look at up to date projects. CefSharp is regulary updated and based on latest chromium framework.

Comment: I have, there is no C# based solution. Only implementing the functionality yourself in C++ which is an overkill. +

Comment: There are no browser engines written in c#. The best you can have is some c# wrapper. You can use cefSharp in wpf or winforms just like any other control https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Your point being? I am looking for wrappers with above mentioned functionalities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94132/discussion-between-dmitry-dovgopoly-and-astralmaster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of other `CEF` based frameworks, one of those might suite your needs. I have tried neither.

- https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx
- https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home

It is possible that the `DOM API` may be removed from `CEF` at some point in the future, so you might want to check the status before investing time in such an effort.

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10652&start=10#p16750

Comment: I can confirm that ChromiumFX exposes some APIs for DOM interaction and supports multi-session profiling, so thank you.